# Como usar o while para pegar todas as linhas

Tags: php

Olá, eu quero pegar todas as linhas da DB com o while ao invés de botar um por um e elas viram variavéis de acordo com a linha da db

```
<?php    
    $link = mysqli_connect($dba['host'], $dba['user'], $dba['pass'], $dba['db']) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
    $query = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $configuracao['perfil'] = $row['perfil'];
    }
```

eu estava usando assim dentro do *while*:

```
$configuracao['perfil'] = $row['perfil'];    
$configuracao['idade']  = $row['idade'];    
$configuracao['local']  = $row['local'];
```

Tem alguma forma do *while* transformar as variáveis de acordo do que está no banco de dados?

Comment: "*transformar as variáveis*", consegue explicar melhor essa parte? Que tipo de "transformação" que você imagina?

Comment: eu estava colocando todos os dados da db em variavéis por exemplo  $configuracao['perfil'] = $row['perfil'];

$configuracao['idade'] = $row['idade'];

$configuracao['local'] = $row['local']; de forma manual, eu quero saber se tem como o while fazer isso pra mim invés de eu por um por um

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você quer carregar em `$configuracao` os dados da tabela. Sendo assim, acredito que não daria pra dinamizar o identificador da coluna (que será a *posição* do vetor). Voceê precisaria descrever todos os campos da tabela para que a associação seja feita:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $configuracao['perfil'] = $row['perfil'];    
    $configuracao['idade']  = $row['idade'];    
    $configuracao['local']  = $row['local'];
}
```

Vale atentar que da forma que está, caso tenha mais de um registro na tabela `clientes`, `$configuracao` terá apenas dados da última ocorrênca. Caso queira armazenar todos, sugiriria o seguinte:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $perfil = $row['perfil'];

    $configuracao['perfil'] = $perfil;    
    $configuracao[$perfil]['idade']  = $row['idade'];    
    $configuracao[$perfil]['local']  = $row['local'];
}
```

Assim, `$configuracao` seria um array de *"perfis"*, e cada perfil teria um array com os demais dados da base.

Comment: muito obrigado, agora entendi :)